# How to automate voice apps testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, voice-recognition, voice

Is there a way to automate the testing of apps that take voice input (similar to Siri)?
Is it possible to test that with Selenium or should I use other tools?

Comment: Hi Al-Muthanna Athamneh, Did u find a way to automate testing of voice based apps?